# Calling groovy script from other groovy script

Tags: groovy

I want to call a groovy script from the other groovy script... anybody can help me in  this ASAP..

example :

Class A having some code and it should call from B

```
 class A{
   static main(args){

     println "Hello.. calling A Class"
   }
 }
```

I want to create a new class like B.groovy

```
class B{
  static main(args){

    // I need code for this to call A.groovy
  }
}
```

Comment: Put them in the same folder. Groovy identifies files in the same directory. Then you can do a simple `new A()`, or, as you are using static methods, `A.main args`

Comment: You only seem to have ever accepted one answer to your questions... I'm not inspired

Comment: what you are telling Mr.Tim.... I am not getting you?

Comment: @ Tim : ohhh... I am new to this forum.. Thanks for giving suggestions..

Answer (score 3):

Putting the following at the top of your script will load the contents of a groovy file.

```
evaluate(new File("/path/to/script/MyScript.groovy"))
```

You could also add this to the groovy classpath if you need to do something like this often.  Hope this helps.

additionally if you need to run other scripts from your script you could do the following...

```
def script = new GroovyShell();
def args = ['Hello World'];
script.run(new File("/path/to/script/MyScript.groovy"), args as String[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Too late for the party (any beer for me?) but here I´ll show you 2 more flavors:

**1)** Remember the concept of Java´s CLASSPATH? That aplies to Groovy (because Groovy is Java!):

"The CLASSPATH variable is one way to tell applications, including the JDK tools, where to look for user classes.”

In order to run the script B.groovy you have to inform the location of the A.groovy (A class):

**groovy –cp c:\groovy\yourscripts c:\groovy\scripts\B.groovy**

The command above is telling the runtime to look in the c:\groovy\yourscripts folder because there is where we have our classes and we need them to run the B.groovy script successfully.

**2)** Use the **[GroovyClassLoader](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html)** to load your scripts at runtime and using the code!

Both ways solve your needs. Now the next question is when to use each?